# How to get user's OS locale in java

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Can anyone tell me how to **get** user's **OS locale** in `Java`. I am creating web application using `Spring MVC` with internationalization support and therefore I need to **retreive** user's **OS's locale**.

I have tried `Locale.getDefault()` but it always gives value as `en-US` even if my system's locale is `fr-FR`

I know how to get the language from user's browser (Using `Accept Header`) but I need OS language settings to be read.

Comment: If you are using Java 7, here is the bug report: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7073906

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Locale.getDefault()` will get the locale of the *server*, so that is definitely not what you want.

The [`Accept-Language`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) HTTP header will specify the client's acceptable language, which is likely done by the web browser by looking at the OS language of the client.

You will then have to parse that value to find a matching locale for you web application.

Comment: it is not done by looking at the OS language of the client. It's browser-specific setting in all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to find out the locale of a web request user then try https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocale()

Answer (score 0):

We're talking about web applications, so in general all you know about your users are what HTTP requests provide (this is a simplification, but as a general rule). What HTTP requests provide in regards of language is the Accept-Language header, nothing more. That is a browser-specific setting you can get. Getting OS language of the web user is not something you are given, so no, you can't get that.

(there are some workarounds, for example if you want to run a java applet to find this out, it is probably possible. However, that would be a path that I would recommend against.)